# Jetty: Why am I seeing only a subset of TLS ciphers on the wire from what Jetty calculates as ENABLED ciphers

Tags: jetty, tls1.2, jetty-9

I am up to tuning TLS ciphers for my application that runs on Jetty-9 server and OpenJDK 1.8.0_u212 and have the following question.

I have retained all the default Java's security settings (java.security file under ${JRE_HOME}/lib/security); and I use BouncyCastleFIPS provider in FIPS mode. And SunJSSE in FIPS mode (parameterized to use BCFIPS as the provider).

I also have a self-signed RSA 2048-bit certificate attached to my server port. (signature algorithm = sha256RSA).

And I limit my app only to use TLS1.2 protocol and exclude some weak ciphers with these settings in *jetty-ssl-context.xml*:

```
    <Set name="ExcludeCipherSuites">
       <Array type="String">
        <Item>.*DES.*</Item>
        <Item>.*RC4.*</Item>
        <Item>.*MD5.*</Item>
        <Item>.*DSS.*</Item>
       </Array>
    </Set>

    <Set name="useCipherSuitesOrder"><Property name="jetty.sslContext.useCipherSuitesOrder" default="true"/></Set>

    <Set name="ExcludeProtocols">
        <Array type="java.lang.String">
          <Item>SSLv2</Item>
          <Item>SSLv3</Item>
          <Item>TLSv1</Item>
          <Item>TLSv1.1</Item>
        </Array>
    </Set>
```

The selected cipher suites after resolving for include/exclude settings is this (dump from after the server starts) –

```
 [java] 2019-08-23 10:39:46.589+0100 DEBUG o.e.j.u.s.SslContextFactory - Selected Ciphers   [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV] of [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
```

- In summary, there are 37 *ENABLED* ciphers out of 43 *SUPPORTED* ciphers.
- Of the 37,  there are:

  > - 12  x     TLS_RSA.* / TLS_ECDHE_RSA.*
  > - 12  x     TLS_ECDH_RSA.* / TLS_DHE_RSA.*
  > - 01  x     EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV

However, when I scan the server port with openssl s_client, I find only the following 12 ciphers `TLS_RSA.* / TLS_ECDHE_RSA.` that shows up. I gather that the certificate *Au* algorithm plays a role in selection of ciphers - which in this case selects RSA. over *.ECDSA.*.

Rest are missing. Notably, I am interested in `the TLS_DHE_RSA.*` which are not coming through.

A. Would someone be able to tell me why? I suspect there are additional layers of filtering that happens which are not apparent here. Jetty dump after start doesnt print the detials when FIPS mode is enabled. (for reasons unknown)

B. And how to get those missing ciphers enabled on the wire? Specifically `the TLS_DHE_RSA.*`

Much appreciate your insights.

## root@hostname:~# cat test.sh

```
    for c in $(openssl ciphers 'ALL:eNULL' | tr ':' ' '); do
    openssl s_client -connect $host:$port\
    -cipher $c -tls1_2 < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo -e "\t$c"
    done
```

## root@hostname:~# ./test.sh

```
    ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
    ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
    ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
    AES256-GCM-SHA384
    AES128-GCM-SHA256
    AES256-SHA256
    AES128-SHA256
    AES256-SHA
    AES128-SHA
```

Comment: The RSA suites ending in SHA (as in SHA0 or SHA1) are vulnerable too

Comment: What does your [server dump](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-dump-tool.html) or `SslContextFactory.dump` show as enabled/disabled?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve for this and get all the desired ".*DHE_.*" by setting this property in java.security file.

-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048

This property can also be injected via call to System.setProperty() in application code or via JVM args.

The reason was that my providers BC were set to operate in FIPS mode which requires a minimum DH Ephemeral key size of 2048 bits.